# How to send the checked radio button value to Server in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to send the checked radio button value to server in angular

i tried but i am getting 500 server error

where as when i am sending only question id that is working

here is the code for CreateController

```
var CreateController = ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mydata = 'ajs works';
    $scope.model = {
        Questions:{}
    };
    $http.get('/Testing/IndexVM').success(function (newdata) {

        $scope.model = newdata;

    });
    $scope.NextQuestion = function () {
        $http.post('/Testing/NextQuestion', {
            quid: $scope.model.Questions.AddQuestionID, selectedopt: $scope.model.Questions.Options.OptionID
        }).success(function (newdata) {

            $scope.model = newdata;

        }); 
}];
```

and here is the code for index view what i am tring to send

```
    <div ng-controller="CreateController">
<tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Question: {{model.Questions.Question}}</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in model.Questions.Options" ng-model="model.Questions.Options.OptionID">
                <td class="switch radius">
                    <input id="{{item.Options}}" type="radio" name="selectedvalue" value="{{item.Options}}">
                    <label for="{{item.Options}}"></label>{{item.Options}}
                </td>
            </tr>
     </div>
```

Comment: `500 server error` means something wrong at server end.

Comment: This is a server error, that means the problem is on server side, This is not a Javascript or jQuery or Angular issue, so show us your front-end code is useless.

Comment: i put the breakpoint in server but did not hit that breakpoint

Comment: i change the code in index and js now i get this error 
Cannot read property 'Options' of undefined

Comment: new code  $http.post('/Testing/NextQuestion', {
            quid: $scope.model.Questions.AddQuestionID, selectedopt: $scope.item.Options.OptionID
        }).success(function (newdata) {

            $scope.model = newdata;

        })   and code of index
<input type="radio" ng-model="item.Options.OptionID"name="selectedvalue" ng-value="item.Options">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the ng-model to the input element so that every radio button has the same ng-model and same name attribute than u have a radio button group and the model has the value of the selected value attribute

so ng-model="model.Questions.Options.OptionID" not "item"

Comment: i also have ng-model="model.Questions.Options.OpitionID"

Comment: <input id="{{item.Options}}" type="radio" name="selectedvalue" value="{{item.Options}} ng-model="model.Questions.Options.OpitionID">

Comment: where to move the input element

Comment: can you please tell me how to get ng-model in angularjs controller

Comment: $scope.model = {
        Questions:{Question:"Your Question", Options:["option1","option2"]}
    }

Comment: than change that ur result not override ur model $scope.result = newdata;

Comment: now u can log and debug and test whats wrong with ur server

Comment: i mean to say that how to get in angularjs controller $http.post method

Comment: i think this is not the right way to use stackoverflow .its like a chat now . dont know how is ur code now what is the error and dont understand your last question. google a bit please how to debug and how to use angular. make sure ur server sends json and parse the result to have a javascript object. if ur server is a restful server than use $resource or restangular . (and mark my question as the right answer to appreciate the time i spend for you)

Comment: no ur ans is not ri8 yet and my server returns json

Comment: last hint - if ur server returns  json  > $scope.model=angular.fromJson(newdata);

Answer (score 0):

Add ng-model in your radio buttons:

```
<input id="{{item.Options}}" type="radio" name="selectedvalue" value="{{item.Options}} ng-model="item">
```

Comment: how to get this item in js

Comment: You use the ng-model (item) and you can send it to the server. Your value in model (ng-model="item"). Use $scope